# How to cut the string using bash command

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

How to cut the following string and retrieve "Not Running" Status in Bash.
I have tried cut command `cut -d"STATUS"`, It is throwing exception

EX:

```
$ echo "NAME(APACHE) STATUS(Not Running)
```

Expected String:

```
Not Running
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `bash`, regex operator `~`

```
string="NAME(APACHE) STATUS(Not Running)"
[[ $string =~ ^.*STATUS\((.*)\)$ ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
Not Running
```

Using `Awk` as `()` de-limiter,

```
echo "NAME(APACHE) STATUS(Not Running)" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[()]"}{print $4}'
Not Running
```

Using a double-fold parameter substitution, as `bash` does not support nested parameter expansions,

```
temp1="${string#*)}"    
temp2="${temp1%*)}"
printf "%s\n" "${temp2#*STATUS(}"
Not Running
```

Using `GNU grep` with its [PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) capabilities, with the `-P` flag,

```
grep -oP '.*STATUS\(\K[^\)]+' <<<"$string"
Not Running
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solutions:

using `sed` command:

```
echo "NAME(APACHE) STATUS(Not Running)" | sed  -rn 's/.*\(([^)]+)\)$/\1/p'
```

---

using `perl` implementation:

```
echo "NAME(APACHE) STATUS(Not Running)" | perl -lne  'print $1 if /\(([^)]+)\)$/'
```

---

using `awk` command(treating braces `)(` as field separator `FS`):

```
echo "NAME(APACHE) STATUS(Not Running)" | awk  'BEGIN{FS="[)(]"}{ print $(NF-1) }'
```

`$(NF-1)` - points to the last non-empty field

---

`\(([^)]+)\)$/` - regex pattern, will match a character sequence between braces at the end of the string

`\1`(within `sed` expression) and `$1`(within `perl` expression) point to the first captured group `(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The command `cut -d` only works with single character delimiters, that's why you cannot use "STATUS" as delimiter.

You may use awk instead, or use cut with another delimiter, for example "(":

```
echo "NAME(APACHE) STATUS(Not Running)"  | cut -d'(' -f3
```

Which will give the output:

```
Not Running)
```

Then you can remove the last ")" with `tr`:

```
echo "NAME(APACHE) STATUS(Not Running)"  | cut -d'(' -f3 | tr -d ')'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `grep` and `tr`:

```
echo "NAME(APACHE) STATUS(Not Running)" | grep -o '([^)]\+)$' | tr -d '()'
```

The regex `([^)]\+)$` matches anything in between parenthesis at the end of the line.

The `tr` command is deleting the parenthesis.